# In tkinter is there a way to draw a smoothed out curved line?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, line

The below provided lines are from the [the tkdocs website](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html#types).

> A line item can actually be a series of line segments, not just one; in
> our example, we could have chosen to use a single line item for each
> complete stroke. The line can also be drawn directly point-to-point,
> or smoothed out into a curved line.

The documentation points out at the end that "*a line(on the tkinter canvas) can be drawn directly point-to-point, or smoothed out into a curved line.*". But I have not yet been able to find a way to do that.

---

**EDIT:**

The full code used in my project is too big and irrelevant to be provided, but given below is a short portion of it, which is concerned with the problem described above. Hopefully the below code can be helpful in describing what I have tried as of yet.

```
def clear_prev_draw_coords(event = None) :
    global last_draw_x, last_draw_y, pen_color, pen_size

    last_draw_x, last_draw_y = None, None
    drawing_coord_list.clear()
    return

def draw() :
    last_img_x = 0
    last_img_y = 0
    canvas.create_line(last_draw_x, last_draw_y, x2, y2, fill = pen_color, width = pen_size, tag = tag, smooth = 1)

    last_draw_x, last_draw_y = x2, y2
    return

def toggle_pen_mode(dummy = None) :
    global mode

    mode = 'pen'

    root.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)
    root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", clear_prev_draw_coords)
    return
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using thus far so people may try help you with that.

Comment: There is a `smooth` option in `Canvas.create_line()` function.

Comment: @Ronald I've posted the code now, hope it helps :)

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I've tried it out, but it does not also make a curved line as I desire.

Comment: You need to supply more than two points to one `create_line()` in order to create a smooth line.

Comment: But the problem is to find the third point. As only the start and end points are being fetched currently.

Comment: How do you expect a smooth line with only two points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [effbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2opK.png)? You can find a ***lot*** of information about all possible flags and options. This mini example creates a curved line with the `smooth`-flag:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.create_line(150,0, 100,50, 50,0, 0,50, smooth=1)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this out but this does not make a smooth and curved line.

Comment: That is strange. Did you try the exact example or did you use it in some modified way? For a curved line you need at least three (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: You might want to consider adding a screenshot to show what the code generated.

Comment: I've tried the smooth = 1, secondly the other thing which is of the x1, y1, x2, y2..... and so on thing for line joints thingy I had seen in effbot docs but I don't see a way to implement it in the drawing program of mine.

Comment: Ohk I see, it works but the third point where can I fetch that from in a drawing application?

Comment: Well, if you want to let the user *add* line-points, you should store all previous points in a list (not only the last two) and add each new point. Let this list be called `points`: eg: `[150,0, 100,50, 50,0, 0,50, 25,0, 0,25]`. You can then update the line in the example with `w.coords(line, *points)`